How to Batch Matrix Multiplication as Keras Layer?
I am trying to do a Batch Matrix Multiplication as a Keras layer, but can't figure it out.
I try to use tf.einsum('cij,cjk->cik', inputs, self.dense_weights) + self.dense_biases
c is the parallele batch
How to do ?
This is how I initialise the weights
        self.dense_weights = self.add_weight(
            shape=(num_layers, inputs, output_units),  
            initializer='random_normal',
            trainable=True,
            name='dense_weights'
        )
        self.dense_biases = self.add_weight(
            shape=(num_layers, 1, output_units),  
            initializer='zeros',
            trainable=True,
            name='dense_biases'
        )


class ParallelDense(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super().build(input_shape)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=[input_shape[1], input_shape[2], self.units], trainnable=True, initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.bias   = self.add_weight(shape=[input_shape[1],                 self.units], trainnable=True, initializer='glorot_uniform')

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.einsum("bml, mlk -> bmk", inputs, self.kernel) + self.bias

This : Efficiently use Dense layers in parallel
